# using bootstrap with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to make my site resopnsive and i have this table i fill with data from a webservice but my class container dont work now and i dont kow why..
Is it the php code that messup the boostrap or is it something i have done wrong?

```
<!--Tabell visa personal-->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="pull-left">
            <h1 class="regHead">Tabell för all personal</h1>
            <table class="table" id="speltabell">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Personnummer</th>
                        <th>Förnamn</th>
                        <th>Efternamn</th>
                        <th>Adress</th>
                        <th>Postnr</th>
                        <th>Ort</th>
                        <th>Hemtelefon</th>
                        <th>Mobil</th>
                        <th>Mail</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>       
    <?php 
    try
    {
        $soap_client = new
        soapclient("http://tsb01.cnap.hv.se/PersonalService/ServicePersonal.svc?wsdl");      
        $result = $soap_client->HamtaAllPersonal();
        var_dump($result);
        foreach ($result->HamtaAllPersonalResult->AllPersonal as $person) 
        {
        echo "<tr />";
        echo "<td>$person->PnrPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->FornamnPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->EfternamnPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->AdressPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->PostnrPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>Bjas</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->HemtelefonPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->MobiltelefonPersonal</td>";
        echo "<td>$person->MailPersonal</td>";

        }    

    }
    catch(SoapFault $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div> <!--Slut tabell-->
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you linking the bootstrap css files correctly in the head?

Comment: you closed the `echo "<tr />` and please up this code at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: drop the ` /` from the `<tr>`. add `echo "</tr>"` after all your `<td>`s, and be nicer to Tabell, she's not a slut.

Comment: yes i link the bootstrap correctly.. the other things work on my site.
I have now droped the / and added it at the end of all td:s.. still dosent work..

Comment: Anyone that can help? Tried diferent things now and still nothing.. :/

Comment: You only need to put the closing `</tr>` after the last `<td>`, not after all.

Comment: sorry for my bad english yes thats what i did only after the last <td>

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem now? Do you have a fiddle or a live example?

Comment: I have trided jsfiddle but it dosent work :/ the php code dont run..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the content in you `foreach` loop with this and learn HTML better:

```
foreach ($result->HamtaAllPersonalResult->AllPersonal as $person) 
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$person->PnrPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->FornamnPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->EfternamnPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->AdressPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->PostnrPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>Bjas</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->HemtelefonPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->MobiltelefonPersonal</td>";
    echo "<td>$person->MailPersonal</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: And putting the `<tr>` first.

Comment: Yes.. i have also tried to delete the php-code and fill the table by hand.. still the same problem. The table dosent fit to the screen when its smaler like a phone.. soo the problem must be with how i use bootstrap.. i will keep google.. :)

Comment: I fixed it by adding this above my table:
<div class="table-responsive">